# Create and persist properly in the MySQL database

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I work with a Spring boot application and this is the entity class I work,

```
@Entity
public class User {

    // form:hidden - hidden value
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    // form:input - textbox
    @Column(name = "name", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(30)", nullable = false)
    String name;

    // form:input - textbox
    @Column(name = "email", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(50)", nullable = false)
    String email;

    // form:input - password
    @Column(name = "password", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(20)", nullable = false)
    String password;

    // form:textarea - textarea
    @Column(name = "address", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)")
    String address;

    // form:input - password
    String confirmPassword;

    // form:checkbox - single checkbox
    @Column(name = "newsletter")
    boolean newsletter;

    // form:radiobutton - radio button
    @Column(name = "sex", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(1)")
    String sex;

    // form:radiobuttons - radio button
    @Column(name = "number")
    Integer number;

    // form:select - form:option - dropdown - single select
    @Column(name = "country", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(10)")
    String country;

    // form:checkboxes - multiple checkboxes
    @ElementCollection
    @NotNull
    List<String> framework;

    // form:select - multiple=true - dropdown - multiple select
    @ElementCollection
    List<String> skill;
}
```

I intend to only create the following columns in the `user` table,

```
  id, 
  name,
  email,
  address,
  password,
  newsletter,
  framework,
  sex,
  Number,
  Country,
  Skill
```

For example, the corresponding SQL will be like (though I don't want to write explicitly),

```
CREATE TABLE user (

  id LONG GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(30),
  email  VARCHAR(50),
  address VARCHAR(255),
  password VARCHAR(20),
  newsletter BOOLEAN,
  framework VARCHAR(500),
  sex VARCHAR(1),
  Number INTEGER,
  Country VARCHAR(10),
  Skill VARCHAR(500)
);
```

The starting controller class,

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;


    private static List<User> populateDefaultUserValues() {

        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

        User user = new User();
        user.setName("Ella");
        user.setEmail("xyz@gmail.com");
        user.setPassword("df32d343H");
        user.setFramework(Arrays.asList("Spring MVC, GWT".split("\\s*,\\s*")));
        users.add(user);


        user = new User();
        user.setName("Alex");
        user.setEmail("alex@hotmail.com");
        user.setPassword("12HH2d343H");
        user.setFramework(Arrays.asList("Spring MVC, GWT".split("\\s*,\\s*")));
        users.add(user);


        user = new User();
        user.setName("Romanna");
        user.setEmail("romanna@hotmail.com");
        user.setPassword("Rommann343");
        user.setFramework(Arrays.asList("Spring MVC, GWT".split("\\s*,\\s*")));
        users.add(user);

        return users;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public String index() {
        return "redirect:/users";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/users")
    public String showAllUsers(Model model) {

        List<User> users = populateDefaultUserValues();

        users.forEach(user -> {
            userService.save(user);
        });

        model.addAttribute("users", userService.findAll());
        return "list";
    }
}
```

When I run the app, I see that this created in the `MYSQL` database,

[image]

How do I omit the `confirmed_password` field and add the columns of `skill` and `framework`? I expect them to be `VARCHAR`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I omit the confirmed_password field

You should use the [@Transient](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html) annotation.

> add the columns of skill and framework?

Since you've marked them as [@ElementCollection](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html) - there will be no columns in `user` table, as you can't persist a collection of values in a single relation attribute (it would violate [1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) restrictions). There are two additional tables, named like `user_framework` and `user_skill`, they are related to `user` table with `user_id` columns.

You may read the [Java Persistense wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection) and the [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections) about collections to find different examples of proper usage. Although, your code is fine and, in common case, you should not worry about database tables, relations and data consistency - ORM framework (Hibernate, by default) will handle all these things for you.

Comment: If you know, would you mind to write little what is the proper way to work with `Collection` in the `@Entity` classes? And, yes, I have 2 other tables in the `MySQL`, I need to know their values are still in the part of the `User` entity

Comment: I've extended my answer with a couple of links and a little explanation about these collection tables.

Comment: This breaks in the corresponding JSP file `<tbody>
            <c:forEach var="user" items="{users}">
                <tr><c:out value="${user.id}"/></tr>
                <tr><c:out value="${user.name}"/></tr>
                <tr><c:out value="${user.email}"/></tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>`  

I get error says `Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property [id] not found on type [java.lang.String]
`

Comment: Have you done other changes, besides @Transient annotation? Cause it's the only change I've suggested. Seems like `userService.findAll()` now returns `List<String>` or something similar.

Comment: No, I only add the @Trasient annotation and now that field is not created in the table. I guess you are right, it becomes somehow the `List<String>` and I can reach some value like `[com.boot.entity.User@97e462af, com.boot.entity.User@42d9788f, com.boot.entity.User@9cfabdc3]
` (I guess they are for the name, email, and password and I still need to access the framework values) with the JSP 

`<tbody>
<td><c:out value="${users}"/></td>
</tbody>`

It will be very helpful for me and the users of the forum if you can provide a complete answer here. I will read your links sure

Comment: Btw, my save was like 
`List<User> users = populateDefaultUserValues();

        users.forEach(user -> {
            userService.save(user);
        });`